# Как выбрать все буквы перед которыми нет чисел с помощью регулярного выражения?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Регулярное выражение ниже по какой то неведомой причине выбирает только -S а не [A, -S] как ожидалось, я не могу понять причину

```
[^\d=][a-zA-Z]
```

A-S-4V+11D=y

буквы после "=" также не нужны

Comment: `[^\d=]` - один символ (не цифра и не `=`), за которым следует один символ из набора `[a-zA-Z]`. За буквой "`A`" следует какой-либо символ из набора `[a-zA-Z]`? Нет, зато за символом "`-`" следует и это "`S`". Вы бы лучше сказали, что из этой строки вам нужно вытащить.

Comment: `[^\d=]` — это предполагает, что должен совпасть как минимум один символ, а начало строки - не символ. Можно пробовать так `([^\d=]|^)[a-zA-Z]`

Comment: @Deonis я хочу вытащить буквы перед которыми нет чисел и которые находятся слева от "=", в данном случае это буквы A и S

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME ваша регулярка вытаскивает буквы и знаки отдельно, а чтобы буквы были со знаками нельзя?

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME хотя в JS всё как надо работает, спасибо

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME: интересно, сильно усложнится регулярка, если после `=` будет буква со знаком (например, `A-S-4V+11D=-y`) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете использовать такое выражение

```
(?<![0-9=])[a-zA-Z]
```

Тест тут: https://regex101.com/r/reAHEE/1

Конструкция, которая тут используется называется "Negative Look Behind"

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=\D)[a-zA-Z]
```

с телефона, так что проверить не могу.
+ если будет объявлять эту регулярку через `new RegExp`, то нужно двойное экранирование для `\D`, то есть так: `(?<=\\D)[a-zA-Z]`.